# Access parent object from function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Short question. I have the following situation:

```
function callbackTest(data, callback) {
     callback.call(data);
}

var map = new Map("Worldmap");
var data = "My data";
callbackTest(data, map.processData);
```

So, my question is, wheather or not it is possible to access the map object from inside the callbackTest function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `map` unless you pass it in, or `processData` has a reference back to `map`.  Basically there's no inherent `.parentObject` property present when dealing with a generic object here.